Having tabs that look like buttons
I have this example that I took from React Fluent UI: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fahztj?file=src%2Fexample.tsx.
I tried to modify it in a way that the component Tab is now a Button, however the tabs do not work any more. It seems that the Tab component has something in built that helps with the functionality.
Is there a way from that example to either:

Make the Button component work as a Tab;
Make the Tab look like a Button?

Is either of these two options even possible?

I think there are multiple ways. One of the quickest might be to simply wrap the buttons in tabs
      <TabList selectedValue={selectedValue} onTabSelect={onTabSelect}>
        <Tab id="Arrivals" value="arrivals">
          <Button icon={<Airplane />}>Arrivals</Button>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="Departures" value="departures">
          <Button icon={<AirplaneTakeOff />}>Departures</Button>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="Conditions" value="conditions">
          <Button icon={<TimeAndWeather />}>Conditions</Button>
        </Tab>
      </TabList>


Thanks! I marked it as a valid answer. This is very helpful for my learning :)
